# python3 reportlab drawImage High to center

Tags: python-3.x, reportlab, drawimage

```
c = canvas.Canvas('data.pdf', pagesize= [width*inch,height*inch])
c.drawImage('dataptah',x,y, width,height)
c.save()
```

I can't height center the picture,
so I need know x and y unit,
or put something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you can use units for the x, y, width, and height values in the `drawImage` call, just as you did for the `pagesize`. Thus, if you know the aspect ratio of your image, you can calculate these values for the exact centered position.

The [reference documentation](https://www.reportlab.com/docs/reportlab-reference.pdf#page=6) mentions two other parameters, that could be helpful:

- `preserveAspectRation=True` keeps the aspect ratio of the image even if the box specified with x, y, width, height has a different aspect ratio.
- `anchor='c'` specifies the anchor position of the image, center in this case.

Thus, if you add these two parameters and center the box on the page, then your image should appear centered as well. Here is an example:

```
c.drawImage('dataptah', 
     width/4*inch, height/4*inch,
     width/2*inch, height/2*inch,
     preserveAspectRatio=True, anchor='c'
)
```